# grunt-replace: replace with list of all files in a directory

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

manually editing the files I import for my webworker is painful.
so i decided to use grunt-replace.

all scripts used by worker are in js/worker/**/*.js

I assume I can use something like

```
replace: {
  dist: {
  options: {
  //something here?
}
  }
```

(taken from https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace#how-to-insert-filename-in-target)

but all I see are options to replace filenames,etc.
I just want to list filenames instead.

Comment: why go to _replace_ if you're not replacing?

Comment: I import scripts using
importScripts("somefolder/fil1.js", "somefolder/file2.js",etc);
when i add a file, modify a folder name, etc in these folders, I have to add it to this already long string